# Shiny-rendering output of power.prop.test function for sample size

Tags: r, statistics, shiny, sample-size

I am pretty new to shiny, and I know y question is fairly simple, but despite doing a lot of research I can not seem to get shiny to render the output of a power of proportions test. I am trying to make a script where a user inputs all the parameters (p1,p2,sig.level,power), and the sample size n is given.  I have tried many different methods, but I usually end up at having no output, or the error "exactly one of 'n', 'p1', 'p2', 'power', and 'sig.level' must be NULL".  Any help is appreciated, thank you!

my code so far:

```
    ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Power Calculator"),
    fluidRow(
    column(12,
       wellPanel(
         helpText("This calculator can help you understand the power of 
                  your experimental design to detect treatment effects. You     
        can choose 
                  between a standard design in which individuals are randomly   
       assigned to treatment or control 
                  and a clustered design, in which groups of individuals are assigned to treatment 
                  and control together."),
         column(4,
                wellPanel(

         numericInput('p1a','prop1', value = 0.12, min = 0.01, max = 0.99),
         numericInput('p2a', 'prop2', value = 0.14, min = 0.01, max = 0.99),
         numericInput('sig.levela','significance level' , value = 0.95, min = 0.9, max = 0.99),
         numericInput('powera', 'power level', value = 0.8, min = 0.75, max = 0.99)
                ),
         column(8,
                wellPanel(
                  htmlOutput("nrequired")

                )
         )
         )
         )
         )
         )
         )
         )
         )

         server<-shinyServer(
        function(input, output) {



        sample.size<-reactive({
  p1<-input$p1a
  p2<-input$p2a
  sig.level<-input$sig.level$a
  power<-input$power.levela

})


output$nrequired <- renderPrint({
power.prop.test(sample.size)
print(sample.size)
})

}
)

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Please do not capitalize the names of R functions when they are not actually capped. It confuses the other newbies. (The error message seems reasonably clear. You gave one argument and the function expected four.)

Comment: sorry, what capitilization are you referring too?  I would also add that I get that error when supplying all arguments (p1,p2,sig.level and power)

Comment: "Power.Prop.Test function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message comes from `power.prop.test` which is caused by passing the reactive expression `sample.size` as parameter to it.

Please, try to modify the server function as follows:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$nrequired <- renderPrint({
    power.prop.test(p1 = input$p1a, p2 = input$p2a, 
                    sig.level = input$sig.levela, power = input$powera)
  })
})
```

BTW: I was wondering about your choice of the `sig.level` parameter of 0.95 while `power.prop.test` is using a default value of 0.05.

Comment: I'm glad you appreciate my answer. Would you mind to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left side, please? Thank you.